# How to copy matches from an extremely large file if it contains no newlines?

Tags: python, linux, bash, perl, grep

The problem is I cannot avoid working with extremely big files which contain no newlines in them:

```
<a>text1</a>...gigabytes of data here, all in one single line...[a text to extract b>
```

What should I do if I want to copy matches from this file (putting every match in a separate line, for convenience)? Say, `<b>.*?</b>`.

If I use

```
grep -Pzo '\[a .*? b>' path/to/input.txt > path/to/output.txt
```

it will just give an error: **memory exhausted** (this is a related question: [grep-memory-exhausted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90036/grep-memory-exhausted)).
Neither sed nor awk won't allow to work with such a file. So, how should I extract matches from it?

Comment: Did you try `tr '\0' '\n' < input.txt`

Comment: I tested `tr '\0' '\n' < path/to/input.txt > path/to/output.txt` now, it does nothing to the input. output.txt remains as the same single line file.

Comment: Line-based tools are not going to work. You are probably better off writing a script in Perl or Python to process the file.

Comment: I edited the tags, accordingly :) But strange, I think this is a very common operation (for example, [vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_search_matches#Copy_matches](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_search_matches#Copy_matches)), but googling the web shows no example of such a script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant BLOCK_SIZE => 64*1024;

my $buf = "";
my $searching = 1;
while (1) {
   my $rv = read(\*STDIN, $buf, BLOCK_SIZE, length($buf));
   die($!) if !defined($rv);
   last if !$rv

   while (1) {
      if ($searching) {
         my $len = $buf =~ m{\[(?:a|\z)} ? $-[0] : length($buf);
         substr($buf, 0, $len, '');

         last if $buf !~ s{^\[a}{};

         $searching = 0;
      } else {
         my $len = $buf =~ m{b(?:>|\z)} ? $-[0] : length($buf);
         print substr($buf, 0, $len, '');

         last if $buf !~ s{^b>}{};

         print("\n");
         $searching = 1;
      }
   }
}
```

Lots of assumptions made:

- Assumes the start tag is spelled exactly `[a`.
- Assumes the end tag is spelled exactly `b>`.
- Assumes each start tag has a corresponding end tag.
- Assumes each end tag has a corresponding start tag.
- Assumes `[a` won't be found between `[a` and `b>`.

Comment: 1. How to use it in console (that is, how to specify names of input and output files)? 2. What if I want to copy `\[a.*?b>` matches? I am not asking about **tags** (I posted `<b>.*?</b>` just as a very basic example), I want to copy **regex-based** matches. I edited the example, accordingly. 3. What will happen if there will be more than 32KB sized match? I am ready to skip such matches, but what exactly will happen with the script?

Comment: 1. `a.pl <file`. 2a. You'll have to look for `[a` (or part thereof at the end of the buffer) instead of `<b>` (or part thereof at the end of the buffer). 2b. Most regex patterns can match an unlimited number of characters, so it's hard to tell if a pattern will match or not without having the entire file to match against.  3. There's a limit to how many times a given certain repetitions can repeat. The limit can be as low as 32K times. That limit has been raised, and it doesn't affect all repetitions. I just played it safe. There are ways around the limit.

Comment: The repetition limit doesn't apply here. Mostly (only?) for `{m,n}`.

Comment: Sorry,  am not a Perl programmer. 1. What is `<file`? There must be **two** paths/filenames - for input and output. 2. Can you edit the script for `[a .*? b>`? 3. I suppose there will be a big problem if, say, the file contains `[a ` somewhere at the beginning and `b>` at the end? Not enough memory! The only way to avoid such problem is to specify a limit in regex, like `[a .{0,64000} b>`, right?

Comment: 1. Redirect input. You already know how to redirect the output. 2. No, you could assume the `b>` is forthcoming and start printing as soon as `[a` is found.

Comment: Changed it so the length of the captured text can be arbitrary long without running out of memory. (Also, the buffer wasn't being flushed when it should have been.)

Answer (score 0):

Grep has [different behavior](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=8152) starting with version 2.21:

> When searching binary data, grep now may treat non-text bytes as line
>   terminators. This can boost performance significantly.

So what happens now is that with binary data, all non-text bytes
(including newlines) are treated as line terminators. If you want to change this
behavior, you can:

- use `--text`. This will ensure that only newlines are line terminators
- use `--null-data`. This will ensure that only null bytes are line terminators

[--line-regexp option with null data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31467045/#31468059)