# --line-regexp option with null data

Tags: bash, null, grep, newline

Consider this command:

```
printf 'alpha\nbravo\ncharlie\n' | grep --line-regexp --quiet bravo
```

grep sees 3 lines separated by newline, and matches the bravo line. Now consider
this command:

```
printf 'alpha\0bravo\0charlie\0' | grep --line-regexp --quiet bravo
```

My thinking tells me that because I have not used `--null-data`, grep should see
1 or even 0 lines separated by newline, and fail to match a `bravo` followed by
newline. However it does not, it succeeds just like the first command, why is
this?

Comment: Those succeed and fail appropriately for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior [was introduced](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=8152) with Grep 2.21:

> When searching binary data, grep now may treat non-text bytes as line
>   terminators. This can boost performance significantly.

So what happens now is that with binary data, all non-text bytes
(including newlines) are treated as line terminators. If you want to change this
behavior, you can:

- use `--text`. This will ensure that only newlines are line terminators
- use `--null-data`. This will ensure that only null bytes are line terminators