# How to read from a logfile

Tags: bash

I want to grep a word with following words after it.
Atm  my bash script writes only the searched word but not the following lines.
Every line starts with the date but not the follwing lines.
In my case is it better to write "while" command with "cut" option?
How can i make it run?

```
read -p "what you want to search?: " Search
grep -i "${Search}" "$1"






2017-03-15 15:23:02,814 ERROR - (8564@xxxxxxx-PC) 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker                 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at com.xxxxxxx.batch.converter.compart.CompartWrapper.transform
    at com.xxxxxxx.batch.converter.compart.CompartWrapper.convert
    at com.xxxxxxx.batch.converter.AbstractConverter.run
    at com.xxxxxxx.batch.converter.fo.FoConverter.foToFormatUnequalFo
    at com.xxxxxxx.batch.converter.fo.FoConverter.convert
    at com.xxxxxxx.batch.converter.fo.FoConverter.call
2017-03-15 15:23:02,847 ERROR - (8564@xxxxxxx-PC)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
    at java.lang.Thread.run
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The quoting in your `grep` command is off, the search term has no closing quotes.

Comment: yes sorry i modified but this not match my question

Comment: 2017-03-15 15:23:02,743  INFO - (8564@xxxxxxx-PC) TIME FOR GET 
2017-03-15 15:23:02,746  INFO - (8564@xxxxxxx-PC) TIME FOR GET
2017-03-15 15:23:02,813 ERROR - (8564@xxxxxxx-PC) Error while generatin
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
      at com.xxxxxxx.batch.converter.compart.CompartWrapper.transform
      at com.xxxxxxx.batch.converter.compart.CompartWrapper
2017-03-15 15:23:02,814 ERROR - (8564@xxxxxxx-PC)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize 
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun

Comment: ... to your question.

Comment: i meant Benjamin... this is a sample from the log file the output must be that what i describe before if i write error i wish error + the following file that starts without date and that why they will not include yet with my script example

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -A1 -i "${Search}" "$1"
```

The "-A1" returns a matched line plus 1 line After. Adjust the number to suit your needs.

Comment: thank you but this help till the new line or the other error line but the goal ist to reach all the error file and after 1 line or 20 they beginn again with info and warn and then again error item line if i write -A1(or more) they show me the info or the warn line too..i think somehow with while comand will help but i dont understand how

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't fully understand at first. It sounds like you could use regular expressions to get what you want. Take a look at this eerily similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826525/bash-how-to-efficiently-manipulate-a-grep-poz-multiline-output

Comment: wow this is more complicate as i can understand but i dont want give up
i think if i read with while (while read param1 param2) the next step to understand how param2 (the error item) dont separate from line where related to error

Answer (score 0):

After 2 week maybee i found a way to search in a logfile
but i need your opinion

```
#!/bin/bash -e 
if [ -e "$1" ] ; 
then
        input="$1"
else
        echo "need name file after script" >&2
        exit
fi
erra()     { grep --color -i -n -P "${search}|\t" "$1";}
infa()     { grep --color -i -n -P "${search}" "$1";}  
searcht()  { [[ $search == [eE]* ]];}
searchiw() { [[ $search == [iIwW]* ]];}
conti()    { read -r -p "another request?[y/n]: " ans
            if [[ $ans == [nN]* ]]
              then
              exit
            fi;}
while :
do
            read -r -p "what do you search?: " "search"
            if  searcht "$1"                
              then
            erra "$1"
            conti "$1"
              else
            searchiw "$1"   
            infa "$1"
            conti "$1" 
            fi
done
```

Comment: Need our opinion on what?

Comment: if that way is the best way

Comment: What does "best" mean?

Comment: the best , the clearly ,the right ...i know that to search in a logfile there are many way but i noob in this job and i really want to know if my way to search a file with exception the usually way is

Comment: What you seem to not understand is that 1) "best" has many different meanings, depending on how it's measured. And many of those metrics are at odds with each other. Therefore, asking what is the "best" without qualify the metrics under consideration is pointless and 2) Stack Overflow isn't here to answer primarily opinion based questions.

Comment: aah now i really understand you...but after that explanation i dont know if with that code i can every time search into a file and search without problem or if usually this way is not the right way to search into a logfile with exception

Comment: Well the answer to that is to test.